# Problem with SVN eclipse Merging

Tags: svn, subversive

Hallo,
I have a very weired problem with my Galileo Eclipse running SVN Subversive. In the past, my manager showed me how to merge my branch to the trunk.
1. Update my copy of the Trunk
2. Right Click, Team->Merge
3. In the URL, I write the URL of my branch, and Depth "Working Copy" and click OK
4. It takes some time for merging and then it shows these red icons where there are conflicts.

I did all these steps above, but the problem is, it doesn't show these red icons at all. But rather it shows me this greater than symbol ">" before the name of each folder, and this means (as far as I know) that changes haven't been committed.

Can anybody help me please? Because I want to commit my work to the trunk!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any conflicts, it should do the merge into your local working copy which you then have to commit to the repository.